# Local Storage of all Events

Tags: javascript, html

```
   function pushButton(buttonValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
        document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
}

    function calculate(equation) {
        var answer = eval(equation);
        document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
    }

HTML:

    <table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen" value="0" ></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(1)" value="Call2Functions">1</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(2)" value="Call2Functions">2</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(3)" value="Call2Functions">3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <div>
```

even after trying this code i a unable store value locally. Pls can anyone help me? Still i am finding solution for this issue..after adding localStorage also i am unable to store values locally
    Kindly help me i have tried a lot...

Comment: `but its not stored locally` - which part of your code even attempts to store anything locally?

Comment: Providing a smallar code section that illustrate your issue make it easier to answer. If there is no problem in the code there is no need to include it.

Comment: Your HTML is totally invalid.

Comment: @LeeTaylor,function pushButton(buttonValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
        document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
} even after using this code i can not able store data locally.an you help me?

Comment: @SANTHIYA Please edit your question and place that code in there.

Comment: @LeeTaylor yes added kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

To Store items in the `localStorage`, you will need to store the value paired with a key using `localStorage.setItem`:

```
var key = 'yourKey'
,   resultToStore = 'test';
localStorage.setItem(key, resultToStore);
```

To retrieve the value, just call `localStorage.getItem` and pass in the key:

```
var returnedResult = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

In your function `pushButton`, you would want to store the value:

```
function pushButton(buttonValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
        document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
}
```

Now whenever page loads, you need to see if there is a value in the localStorage and get that value if it's there:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oldAnswer = localStorage.getItem('answer');
    if(oldAnswer) {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = oldAnswer;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SANTHIYA SO is not a rent-a-coder site. Show some attempt at using Moishe's code and come back if you have problems. If you do have problems, then please explain the **exact** issues.

Comment: @SANTHIYA `localStorage.setItem(answer,);` would be setting the value of answer as the key. (There is a problem with the syntax too because you aren't passing in anything as the value) Instead you would want to do something like `localStorage.setItem('answer', answer);` where the String `answer` is the key and the value of answer is what's being stored.

Comment: if you were able to successfully store the value in the localStorage upon calculating it, now you just need to add a function that gets called when page loads and in it, you try to get item from localStorage with localStorage.getItem('answer'). If it is not there, you use default of zero.

Comment: @MoisheLipsker please i am stressed trying can you add code so that i learn it

Comment: @MoisheLipsker yes i tried your code not stored locally,actually i am trying this code to start learning to build mobile apps.. onload is anyother way to code for device to create offline apps?